# How to exclude a statement from first iteration of a loop in c#?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in C#. i want to implement this concept.

```
for (int i = 0; i < TestCases.Count; i++)
{
    // some statements
    if (i > 0)
    {
        // some statements

        Runthisfunction();

        // some statements        
    }
}
```

I want to run them in the way showns above.
Inshort, i want Runthisfunction() to execute from second iteration. i don't know how to do that. can you please guide me ?

Comment: But aren't you doing it already due to the `if (i > 0)`?

Comment: yes i am doing it already. but adbdef are long piece of code. so i do not want to repeat it. i am looking to optimize the code

Comment: Your abcd encoding was unclear and has been edited out. If this is a repeating-code issue then make that much clearer.

Comment: What you may actually need is to wrap a bunch of statements into a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and change the flag to do this example is following

```
bool flag=false;
for(int z=0;z<TestCases.Count;z++)
{
   if(z!=0)
    flag=true;

   if(flag)
      RunthisFunction();
}
```

you can achieve your goal with this technique! because Runthisfunction(); will not execute at first iteration!

Comment: You can skip the if statement if you put flag=true; behind RunThisFunction();

Answer (score 1):

what you have will work; there are other things you could do, though - for example:

```
if(TestCases.Count != 0) { abcdef on item 0 }
for(int i = 1 ; i < TestCases.Count ; i++)
{
    abcdef;
    Runthisfunction();
    efg
}
```

This just changes the loop to start at 1 instead of 0, and runs 0 manually.

Comment: @Sayse oops! fortunately, it wouldn't have compiled, so the compiler would have stopped my fail

Comment: The compiler would have only complained that there wasn't a semi colon :)

Comment: it looks good. but i have decided to use the second answer. thanks:)